# PHP - PayPal Integration, failed running my custom transaction function after payment accepted

Tags: php, paypal

I have tried using a tutorial script for PayPal payment in the past and it worked. Now it doesn't. The script is simple, all I need is this one page for processing payment:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  include ('mydbconfig.php');

  // payPal settings
  $paypal_email = 'seller@yahoo.com';
  $return_url = 'https://www.mytestsite.com/paypal-thanks.php';
  $cancel_url = 'https://www.mytestsite.com/paypal-cancel.php';
  $notify_url = 'https://www.mytestsite.com/paypal-notify.php';

  $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
  $item_amount = $_POST['item_amount']; //price

  // check if paypal request or response
  if (!isset($_POST["txn_id"]) && !isset($_POST["txn_type"])){
    // firstly append paypal account to querystring
    $querystring .= "?business=".urlencode($paypal_email)."&";

    // append amount& currency (£) to quersytring so it cannot be edited in html

    //the item name and amount can be brought in dynamically by querying the $_POST['item_number'] variable.
    $querystring .= "item_name=".urlencode($item_name)."&";
    $querystring .= "amount=".urlencode($item_amount)."&";

    //loop for posted values and append to querystring
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
      $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
      $querystring .= "$key=$value&";
    }

    // Append paypal return addresses
    $querystring .= "return=".urlencode(stripslashes($return_url))."&";
    $querystring .= "cancel_return=".urlencode(stripslashes($cancel_url))."&";
    $querystring .= "notify_url=".urlencode($notify_url);

    // Append querystring with custom field
    //$querystring .= "&custom=".USERID;

    // Redirect to paypal IPN
    header('location:https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'.$querystring);
    exit();

  } else { // response from Paypal

    // read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
      $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
      $value = preg_replace('/(.*[^%^0^D])(%0A)(.*)/i','${1}%0D%0A${3}',$value);// IPN fix
      $req .= "&$key=$value";
    }

    // assign posted variables to local variables
    $data['item_name'] = $_POST['item_name'];
    $data['item_number'] = $_POST['item_number'];
    $data['payment_status'] = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $data['payment_amount'] = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $data['payment_currency'] = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $data['txn_id'] = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $data['receiver_email'] = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $data['payer_email'] = $_POST['payer_email'];
    $data['custom'] = $_POST['custom'];

    // post back to PayPal system to validate
    $header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

    $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

    if (!$fp) {
      // HTTP ERROR
      header('location: https://www.mytestsite.com/paypal-error.php?tr='.$data['txn_id'].'&in='.$data['item_name'].'&pe='.$data['payer_email'].'&pa='.$data['payment_amount'].'&ps='.$data['payment_status']);

    } else {
      fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
      while (!feof($fp)) {
        $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
        if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
          //payment accepted, insert transaction to my database
          //function to insert transaction here

        } else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
          //something to do if failed

        }
      }
      fclose ($fp);
    }
  }
?>
```

After the process is completed, I checked and the payment is paid successfully, but my function or anything I wrote in *//function to insert transaction here* won't be executed. In the end I'm forced to do the function on paypal-thanks.php page. Is there something's wrong in the script?

Is this script can be used to send more than one item purchasing? My cart is my own custom made and I only want to send Item name, number, and price detail, and total price to PayPal order summary.

I checked the other PayPal integration questions here, and most of them direct me to PayPal tutorial, documentation, or integration wizard which're confusing. I use this simple script before because I can't understand PayPal documentation (and the sample code, it didn't even let me know where to start) :(

And lastly my ultimate question, is this script is the correct and secure way to do a payment transaction?

Comment: While ago i was stuck in similar problems. The code suggested in PayPal guide is not updated. Try use: https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN it's a PHP5 class to handle paypal IPN Notification, it's robust and easy to use

Comment: After reading this, I search for another simple tutorial and found one. With a little tweak I can adjust it into multiple item (cart) payment, I'll post the link as solution @eldblz

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

instead of

```
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

i think it is better to use CURL instead of socket